# Student Performance using Decision Tree in Weka

Tags: weka, j48

I'm new at using weka. I want to use j48 for my project on Student Performance. I do not know how to edit the rules though. For example I have 8 subjects and need to get the average after getting the average if the total grade < 60 : Needs Improvement. How do I do that? Sorry this is all very confusing for me.

Comment: Would I need to provide the average already? My project is similar to this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9AU-zqs71M but I do no understand how to change the rules.